# .NET solution for creating a Portal

Tags: .net, portal

What would be a good framework/package to create a portal like PageFlakes, or [iGoogle](http://www.google.com/ig)? We are looking to create a employee/HR portal that offers HR services to employees but we also want a product that is flexible enough so that we can use it to create portals for other applications/purposes.

I've looked at [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal/overview) and [Vyre Unify](http://www.vyre.com/vyre_unify/) and they look interesting. I am just wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

Would prefer a .NET solution. Open Source would be best but commercial solution is acceptable too. Security is also a big concern.

Answer (score 0):

I've used DotNetNuke (http://www.dotnetnuke.com) in the past with great succcess.  It has a great community and track record.  There are also enormous amounts of third-party solutions to extend core functionality (http://www.snowcovered.com).

In addition, you may consider looking at Windows SharePoint Services, however development within that can be both a licensing and development nightmare.

Rolling your own just doesn't make sense given the overhead of redoing all of the security and content management pieces.

Comment: At this point, we've ruled out SharePoint. Like you said, it's too cumbersome both development and licensing wise.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Omar AL Zabir's DropThings project, which I think was the basis for PageFlakes. Open source, and .NET:

http://code.google.com/p/dropthings/